# Remove duplicate value from another dictionary

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries there response is like

```
    Array1= {'date': '30-06-18     22:23:01 (UTC)', 'FullName': 'NoMatch', 'image': 'Events/mili/DSC_0150.jpg', 'EventName': 'mili'}
               ,{'date': '30-06-18     22:23:01 (UTC)', 'FullName': 'NoMatch', 'image': 'Events/mili/DSC_0154.jpg', 'EventName': 'mili'} 



     Array2= {'date': '30-06-18     22:23:01 (UTC)', 'FullName': 'NoMatch', 'image': 'Events/mili/DSC_0151.jpg', 'EventName': 'mili'}
               ,{'date': '30-06-18     22:23:01 (UTC)', 'FullName': 'NoMatch', 'image': 'Events/mili/DSC_0154.jpg', 'EventName': 'mili'}
```

And same way in other dictionary , I want to do that is i want to get Array1 having no Array2[k]['image']  same value . Mean no image of array2 should in array1 .

**Result dictionary should be**

```
Array3 = {'date': '30-06-18     22:23:01 (UTC)', 'FullName': 'NoMatch', 'image': 'Events/mili/DSC_0150.jpg', 'EventName': 'mili'}
```

i tried to do this

```
list3 = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
```

but i cant access indexs and value in this loop

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave an example of two arrays and the desired result.

Comment: @EugenePrimako  done

Comment: They're dictionaries, not arrays

Comment: @cricket_007   this giving me all images of array2  array2_images = set(item['image'] for item in Array2)    . but empty array after comparison

Comment: I didn't give you that code

Comment: @cricket_007 yes any help  ?

Comment: Eugene's answer looks fine. He shows the output, so I don't understand why you're seeing something empty. Try reinitializing your variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we build a set of images that we want to exclude, then build a resulting list of items.

```
array2_images = set(item['image'] for item in Array2)
array3 = [item for item in Array1 if item['image'] not in array2_images]
# [{'date': '30-06-18     22:23:01 (UTC)', 'EventName': 'mili', 'FullName': 'NoMatch', 'image': 'Events/mili/DSC_0150.jpg'}]
```

Comment: in array2_images  all images are occurring . but array3 is empty result

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the `image` values within `Array2` within those in `Array1`. The list comprehension can do that this way:

```
temp = [i['image'] for i in Array2]

print([i for i in Array1 if i['image'] not in temp])
```

Comment: This will work, but inefficienly: it will recalculate ```[i['image'] for i in Array2]``` for every element of ```Array1```.

Comment: @EugenePrimako Good point. Worth reading the Array2 image values once prior to the list comprehension. Made the edits above